# Trying to make specific messaging appear in Shopify Order Confirmation email based on the following liquid variables of products in an order

Tags: shopify, liquid

Trying to make specific messaging appear in Shopify Order Confirmation email based on the following liquid variables of products tags and shipping country - so if a product has the following product tag 'data-age-verification-required' and the order has a shipping address of the United Kingdom 'GB' then show the following message "TEST - Please note: If your order included an Age Restricted item, we will need to verify your age before your order can proceed. Orders for Next Day delivery may be delayed pending AgeChecked verification. Please see below for further details."

{% for tag in line.product.tags %} {% if tag == 'data-age-verification-required' %} and {% if checkout.shipping_address.country_code == 'GB' %}

TEST - Please note: If your order included an Age Restricted item, we will need to verify your age before your order can proceed. Orders for Next Day delivery may be delayed pending AgeChecked verification. Please see below for further details.

{% endif %} {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

use something like this example, do not use 2 times if the condition

```
{% assign isTag = false %}
 {% for tag in line.product.tags %} 
  {% if tag == 'data-age-verification-required' %}
    {% assign isTag = true %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then use it like this

```
{% isTag  and checkout.shipping_address.country_code == 'GB' %}
  content goes here 
{% endif %}
```